# Why python gearman worker not showing errors

Tags: python, gearman

I have some errors while using gearman in python:

```
import gearman

gm_worker = gearman.GearmanWorker(['localhost:4730'])

def task_listener_reverse(gearman_worker, gearman_job):
    print d
    print 'Reversing string: ' + gearman_job.data
    return gearman_job.data[::-1]

# gm_worker.set_client_id is optional
gm_worker.set_client_id('python-worker')
gm_worker.register_task('reverse', task_listener_reverse)

# Enter our work loop and call gm_worker.after_poll() after each time we timeout/see socket activity
gm_worker.work()
```

Here are error in `print d`, but it is not showing any errors(like `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`). Failed status returns to gearman client. But on gearman worker no errors is displayed. It's working and receiving new connections

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

In Gearman Protocol failed jobs don't have a result.

You can override the "on_job_exception" method on the worker to do whatever logging you'd like. This is the default so you only get a failed job with false

```
def on_job_exception(self, current_job, exc_info):
    self.send_job_failure(current_job)
    return False
```

Or you can override it and skip the self.send_job_failure with complete code and the client and look at the result and decide if the result has an error code. But then all jobs will never fail.

**Version 1.2**

BTW in the 1.2 tree you can do this:

gearmand --exceptions

So that exceptions are enabled on the server. This saves the need for the client to do this.